# How to generate unique numbers in range?

Tags: javascript, synchronization

How can I generate unique numbers in range 100000 - 999999 in `javascript`?

I'm building a game, in which players can enter rooms to play together.
Each player who want to enter a room has to write the room number,
hence I want the numbers to be as small as possible (6 digits).

Since the requests are async, I need to find a way to allocate the room number
and make sure only 1 request will receive it.
(I can also argue the the backend may need to scale in the future,
so it has to be a 3rd party service).

Moreover, I want to reuse "released" numbers,
which are rooms that have been closed.

For example:

Player `a` open a room number `100`.
Player `b` open a room number `101`.
Player `a` close the room.
Player `c` open a room number `100`.

How can I manage to do it?

Comment: What is your code since now? What did you try already? Are you working with arrays or objects? etc. Try to be more specific, please.

Comment: I don't see how more details will help.. it's a generic question, like how does `kahoot!` generate the room numbers

Answer (score 1):

First you define your range, generate random `Math.floor(Math.random() * range )` then you add them to an array to check it as reference to not allow duplicates

```js
var range = 100000
var choosenArr = [];
var choosen = 0;
choosen =  Math.floor(Math.random() * range );
if(choosenArr.indexOf(choosen) > -1){
  choosen =  Math.floor(Math.random() * range );  
}
choosenArr.push(choosen);

console.log(choosen)
console.log(choosenArr)
```

Comment: @JonasW. Done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use Max value to call this method.

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

console.log(getRandomInt(3));
// expected output: 0, 1 or 2

console.log(getRandomInt(1));
// expected output: 0

console.log(Math.random());
```

// expected output: a number between 0 and 1

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var closer = [];
var room = Math.random()*899999+100000;
for(var i = 0; i < closer.length; i++){
  if(closer[i] == room){
    var room = Math.random()*899999+100000;
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add your code that you tried 

 but for example after you have a code for log in:

```
    <script>
    var room =[];
    var user_name='a'; //have logged in user's name
    function sel_room(){
        var i=document.form.room.value;

                 if(isNaN(i)==true || i<100000 || i>=1000000)
                 {
                     alert("please select between 100000-999999");
                     return;
                 }

                 if(document.form.btn.value == 'Exit')
                 {
                     room[i]=null;
                     document.form.btn.setAttribute("value","Go");
                     document.form.room.removeAttribute("disabled");
                     return;
                 }

                 if(room[i]==null)
                 {
                     room[i]=user_name;
                     alert("you'r in room " + i);
                     document.form.room.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
                     document.form.btn.setAttribute("value","Exit");
                 }
                 else
                     alert("already used! please select another one"); 

                 }
    </script>

    <form name="form">
            <div>       
                inser room number:  
                        <input type="text" size="20" name="room" />
                        <br />
                        <input type="button" name="btn" value="Go" onclick="sel_room()" />

            </div>              
    </form>
```